# How To Check AWS Glue Schema Before ETL Processing?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue

I want to validate the schema *before* the ETL processing using AWS Glue. I am trying to do everything in Glue to avoid using Airflow or other tools.

The flow is S3 raw data -> crawl S3 data in Glue -> perform schema check -> basic ETL using AWS Glue (a basic select * for now) -> output to S3 -> perform ad hoc queries as a check before processing further using EC2 installed ETL software. The idea is if one step fails, I want to send out a notification (email or otherwise) of what failed and where.

Sample data file: the first table (OrderDate, region,...) from [this link](https://www.contextures.com/xlSampleData01.html)

Option 1: The AWS Glue ETL script performs a mapping of the fields within the script. If there is an invalid field type (e.g. an int is in the date column) will the script 'fail' and stop? I have not seen a way within the script to validate the schema only prior to processing.

Sample script line in PySpark:

```
applymapping1 = ApplyMapping.apply(frame = datasource0, mappings = [("orderdate", "string", "orderdate", "date"), ("region", "string", "region", "string"), ("rep", "string", "rep", "string"), ("item", "string", "item", "string"), ("units", "long", "units", "int"), ("unitcost", "double", "unitcost", "double"), ("total", "double", "total", "double")], transformation_ctx = "applymapping1")
```

Option 2: I was reading up on Glue Classifiers. I have built up a test CSV classifier. I am unsure how to apply it to my actual crawled data though as there are no options to link this together. If the classifier fails, will the ETL script still run?

Sample classifier: [Sample Classifier](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9E7ca.png)

Workflows require triggers, triggers require ETL scripts, so I'm unsure how to add the classifier. I am assuming the classifier is imposed when the crawling is happening, but it is unclear how.

Answer (score 0):

Option 1:

No it will not fail. Schema will become struct e.g.

```
struct : choice
|   |-- int
|   |-- date
```

You may use `dynamicframe.resolveChoice()` method to resolve datatype.

Check:

1. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-programming-python-samples-medicaid.html
2. https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-glue-samples/blob/master/examples/resolve_choice.md

Option 2:

In Crawler itself, you can set classifier. While crawling over data, crawler will use classifier.

If classifier fails, crawler may fail...nothing to do with ETL script.

Comment: Option 1: Ok, but I want to ensure the ETL is blocked if the schema is wrong. Is it possible within the script to block further processing? Option 2: Ah okay, just saw how you add a classifier to the crawler itself. The classifier imposes on the crawl, so if there is incorrect data given a schema, the crawl will fail?

Comment: Is there a way to change the data type of the data being crawled? For example, the first column of the sample data above is coming up as a string instead of date, which then is not showing erroneous data.

Comment: Option 1: You can write lambda/python shell job to check and start ETL after schema check from it. Lambda is right option if you want to start it immediately after crawler is completed.  You have to write cloudwatch event for triggering lambda.


if date is in presto date format (https://prestodb.github.io/docs/current/language/types.html#date-and-time) , then it will show date datatype otherwise string. Crawler doesn't have option to set date format.

Comment: For option 2 - I added some bad data - and when the crawler now runs it just changes the data type instead of actually surfacing the data is bad. This means I need to use Lambda and Option 1 instead?

Comment: Crawler is not data cleansing tool :-) So it will not say data is bad. It will just try to find schema by crawling data

Comment: Ah okay! But then can I not make a Glue ETL script to just check the data falls into a schema e.g. the first column is all date type and if yes, continue with the workflow, if no, stop?

Comment: Yes data validation/quality check is part of ETL. You can write logic in ETL to do it. What you want to validate and how you want to repair/reject data is business specific logic. So it should be part of your ETL Glue Job.

Comment: Can you kindly upload a sample for my reference? I had a few people ask me about this also hence would be good to post here (even a small simple table example)? I don't want the ETL to execute if the validation fails, hence thought I would have 2 scripts?